# Invalid certificate error appears on my web server for 10 minutes and then disappears

Tags: certificates, http, attack-prevention, incident-response

I have a raspberry pi that hosts a web server and has a DDNS registered through no-ip. I just had an issue connecting to my webserver because a certificate appeared to be installed on this server that actually corresponded to the domain name vlad.cool. Changing from HTTPS to HTTP did nothing, as the server appeared to forcefully upgrade my connection. After 10 minutes, this issue disappeared on its own.

I've inspected connection attempts to my raspberry, and all successful ones seem to have been me connecting. SSL was also disabled for my apache server.

What could have caused this? Was it an attack on my local network, or my raspberry? I have no default passwords anywhere.

I had no such issues with other websites, both HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: Is it plausible that there was a lapse between your personal IP rotating and your server updating the no-ip DDNS? I.e. a short lapse of time where the no-ip-registered domain name would target the wrong server, due to ISP arcane IP rotation schemes?

Comment: Yes, its plausible. There are a lot of DNS forwarders which don't handle zero TTLs as intended. Although I'm a bit confused how the OP saw an invalid certificate when he knew SSL was disabled (did he type HTTPS by accident?)

Comment: @symcbean no, my connection was automatically upgraded from HTTP to HTTPS. The issue didn't reappear, but I was a little worried about the fact that there might be a MITM attack on my network.